# How to create a list-column with tibble::tribble()?

Tags: r, list, purrr, tibble

When building a tibble from scratch using `tribble()`, how can I set up a column as a "list-column" so it could include data of different classes?

For example, consider the following code where I have one logical value and one numeric value.

```r
library(tibble)

some_numeric <- 5
some_logical <- TRUE

my_df <-
  tribble(~name, ~value,
        "logical", some_logical,
        "numeric", some_numeric)
```

Whereas I was expecting `my_df` to look like:

```r
## # A tibble: 2 x 2
##   name    value    
##  <chr>   <list>   
## 1 logical <lgl [1]>
## 2 numeric <dbl [1]>
```

I actually got this:

```r
## # A tibble: 2 x 2
##   name    value
##   <chr>   <dbl>
## 1 logical     1
## 2 numeric     5
```

---

Sure, there's this way using `tibble()` that works:

```r
tibble(name = c("logical", "numeric"),
       value = list(some_logical, some_numeric))

## # A tibble: 2 x 2
##   name    value    
##   <chr>   <list>   
## 1 logical <lgl [1]>
## 2 numeric <dbl [1]>
```

But I wanted to create it row-wise using `tribble()`, and the following doesn't work either:

```r
tribble(~name, ~value,
          "logical", list(some_logical),
          "numeric", list(some_numeric))

## # A tibble: 2 x 2
##   name    value     
##   <chr>   <list>    
## 1 logical <list [1]> ## <--- I don't want nested list but nested *logical* vec
## 2 numeric <list [1]> ## <--- I don't want nested list but nested *double* vec
```

---

**So my question is,** is there a simple way to use `tribble()` to set up a list-column in which each value is a nested vector and not a nested list?

Comment: I think it's basically not possible, as in a tibble or a data frame every column is an atomic vector so every element in a given column should be of the same type. That's why a logical vec or a double vec both will be coerced to a list type in a column.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR, but if that's the case, then how come `tribble(~x,  ~y, "a", 1:3, "b", c(FALSE))` makes `y` a list-column instantly?

Comment: Dear @Emman it has to be a list. Because column y contains an integer vector and a logical one and since a column in data frame (tibble) cannot be of 2 different classes both will be stored under the type list. Each column can't have 2 different types at the same time and these two underlying components are nested due to different length.

Comment: And since you said you don't want a nested list, I thought it's not possible for them to be nested without creating a list column.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)


f <- tribble(~name, ~value,
        "logical", as.vector("some_logical", mode = "list"),
        "numeric", as.vector("some_logical", mode = "list"))

f
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   name    value     
#>   <chr>   <list>    
#> 1 logical <list [1]>
#> 2 numeric <list [1]>

f$value
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] "some_logical"
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] "some_logical"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>